# Htaccess redirection with random number

Tags: .htaccess

I try to redirect to my home page old pages that end with random numbers. All my urls end like this: `/book-detail.php? b=20275`

I tried this code but I can’t make it work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /book-detail\.php([?#][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^book-detail\.php https://www.test.uk/? [L,R=301]
```

Someone can help me?
thank you.

Comment: Does that parameter matter in _any_ way? Do you need to redirect only when it was present, but just `/book-detail.php` on its own should not redirect? If the answer to both these questions is No, then why are you checking the request with a RewriteCond in the first place?

Comment: What you posted should "work". (I assume you don't have a literal _space_ at the start of the query string, but even if you did the regex would still match and it should "work".) However, take heed from 04FS's comment - it looks like you are making this more complicated than it is?

Comment: Sorry, yes /book-detail.php should be redirect also on homepage. MrWhite, can you explain where is the space? Thanks

Comment: I take the liberty of asking for help again. I did several searches and I ended up writing this code, yet I think I’m not far away but it still doesn’t work.
What does he have a lead on?
Redirect ^/?book-detail.php?b=([0-9]+)$ /books-by-category/$1 [R=301]